# Youtube_it gem Invalid type: must be one of: top_rated, top_favourites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, youtube-api

When I try to do something like this:

```
=@yt_session.videos_by(@video.yt_youtube_id)
```

With youtube_id being not one of those top_rated, top_favourites etc. I get below error:

```
Invalid type, must be one of: top_rated, top_favorites, most_viewed, most_popular, most_recent, most_discussed, most_linked, most_responded, recently_featured, watch_on_mobile
```

This is with Youtube_IT gem in Rails 4

Is there a way to retrieve this video using this gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to use `video_by` instead of `videos_by`?